# Jquery - hover changes to click after several resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to build a basic tab-navigation. When I hover about a tab (step), then the background of the tab gets green. 
But after several hovers/resizes of the browser, hover doesnt't work anymore. Then I have to click on the tab in order to get the green background. It kind of freezes.

Thats the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rob_the_mob_87/L84kyym1/

Here is my minimal code:

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Tabs</title>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/static.js">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="process_step active" id="1">Step 1</div>
    <div class="process_step" id="2">Step 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
.process_step{

}

.active{
  background-color: green;
}
```

static.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindShowStepHandlers()
});

this.bindShowStepHandlers = function () {
    $('.process_step').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            var clickedStepId = $(this).attr('id');
            openStep(clickedStepId);
          });
      });
}

this.openStep = function (clickedStepId) {

      $('.process_step').each(function() {
            var stepId = $(this).attr('id');

            if (stepId == clickedStepId) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
      });
}
```

Comment: please create snippet or jsfiiddle demo. then i can help you

Comment: There is nothing in the code which can create the issue, However you can improve the code as https://jsfiddle.net/L84kyym1/1/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: You are you simply using jQuery for that when you have `:hover` in css.
Can be done as https://jsfiddle.net/jenkinsshubham/L84kyym1/2/

Comment: strange, after hovering over step one, minimizing the jsfiddle, and then hovering again, I have to click in order to get step2 green ( I use Google Chrome, and MacOS)

Comment: sorry guys, seems to be a general problem/behavior on my mac. I have the same effect even on other websites which use hover ...

Comment: check this updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ayatrahmani/vqLmbv6m/2/

Answer (score 0):

> check this snippet below. i think it is what you want..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  bindShowStepHandlers()
});

this.bindShowStepHandlers = function() {
  $('.process_step').each(function() {
    $(this).on('mouseenter',function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $(this).on('mouseleave',function() {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
      
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.process_step {}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="process_step active" id="1">Step 1</div>
  <div class="process_step" id="2">Step 2</div>
```